# text cleaning gsub remove everything until newline is found

Tags: r, regex

```
have <- ('Good luck!!!

          ___________________
          Disclaimer: This email, including attachment ....
          .............
          
          Great!!!   
         ')

have <- ('Good luck!!!
          Great!!!
         ')
```

I'm dealing with email-like dataset which I want to clean before further analysis.
There're some constant structures such as a `Disclaimer` section which is preceded and followed by a newline, which I think should be possible with regex. But the length of the disclaimer may vary due to truncation.

What I've tried currently is below

```
gsub(pattern = 'Disclaimer([\\s\\S]*)[\\n|\\r\\n|\\r]{2}', replacement = '', have)
```

Comment: If you just want to remove the line with the Disclaimer, you can use `gsub(pattern = 'Disclaimer[^\\n]+', replacement = '', have)`.

Comment: Like this? `^\s*Disclaimer.*` https://regex101.com/r/zxbWRR/1

Comment: @Bas the Disclaimer can span multiple lines, and embedded within email conversations. So the regex I'm looking for is something like remove text starting with 'Disclaimer' until newline is found.

Comment: @Thefourthbird if I use * at the end, that assumes there's nothing else after Disclaimer. Disclaimer text can be found many times within the same email.

Comment: @AfiqJohari Then you could match a newline `^\s*Disclaimer.*\r?\n` Or 2 newlines `^\s*Disclaimer.*\r?\n\r?\n` or `^\s*Disclaimer: \S.*\r?\n` https://regex101.com/r/nDdzwT/1

Comment: @AfiqJohari, my regex exactly selects all text starting with 'Disclaimer' until a newline is found. I think you don't mean newline, but rather a blank line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
have <- trimws(gsub("(?m)^\\s*_{3,}\\R\\h*Disclaimer:.*(?:\\R.*\\S.*)*+\\s*", "", have, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/NABa49). Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2nbdE/1).

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on ()
- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - any zero or more whitespace chars
- `_{3,}` - three or more `_`s
- `\R` - a line break
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `Disclaimer:` - a text
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\R.*\S.*)*+` - zero or more non-blank lines
- `\s*` - any zero or more whitespace chars.

Comment: Thanks, looks more complicated that I thought it was :D

Comment: @AfiqJohari Well, you may use a quicker pattern variation, `"(?m)^\\s*_{3,}\\R\\h*Disclaimer:.*(?:\\R\\h*\\S.*)*\\s*"`, no possessive quantifier (`*+`) is actually necessary, but chaning `.*\S` to `\h*\S` gives it some boost.